# Air in the plumbing problem

Tags: plumbing

I have a plumbing system just like this picture in my house:

[image]

The water comes from the water tank that is on the top of the house. In this particular situation shown in the picture, the water goes to the first floor, enters in a forked connection and goes to the tap 2, in the first floor, and to the tap 1, in the second floor. This is a project failure, the connection should be in the second floor, due to this, I'm having problems with air inside the tube that links the tap 1 with the connection. I think the air is getting into the tube by tap 1.

Tap 2 is working nice. Is not always I have tap 1 not working. When I take the air off the tube, it comes back to work, but, by the time passing, 6 months approximately, tap 1 stops flowing water.

How I can avoid this situation without change the tube system? I thought about a retention valve connected to the tap 1, would it work?

Comment: I'm not sure if it would work, but it's worth a try: you could try installing a water hammer chamber in tap 1. That would give some place for water vapor/air to collect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Air probably collects in the lines when faucets are in use at differing flow rates and then one is turned on suddenly. For example consider the upper faucet operating at a small trickle and the lower faucet is off. Then the upper faucet is suddenly turned on full blast. The straight through flow to the lower faucet from the forked fitting could actually act like a suction on the upper pipe for a moment and probably take in a small gulp of air from the upper faucet.

If your fork in the piping looks like this:

[image]

You may want to try a fork that looks more like this:

[image]

. . .with the water flow from the tank entering as shown by the arrow. In this scheme there will be less possibility of the straight through flow suddenly starting creating a suction from above.